# Display more than one data table in one SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list, sharepoint-rest-api, 2019

Is there anyway of display more than one data table from different lists in the same page?

Instead I get the following error:

> DataTables warning: table id=Employee - Cannot reinitialize DataTable.

Also tried using different table ID for each table.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://onlysharepoint2013.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePointSky/SiteAssets/RetriveListItemsRestAPI.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>

<table id="Employee" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    GetItems();
});

function GetItems() {
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var oDataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DirectorList')/items?$select=Title,First_Names,Last_Name";
$.ajax({
url: oDataUrl,
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
headers: {
"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
},
success: OnSuccess,
error: OnFailure
});
}

function OnSuccess(data) {
try {
$('#Employee').DataTable({
"aaData": data.d.results,
"aoColumns": [
{
"mData": "Title"
},
{
"mData": "First_Names"
},
{
"mData": "Last_Name"
}
]
});
} catch (e) {
alert(e.message);
}
}

function OnFailure(data, errMessage) {
alert("Error: " + errMessage);
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to display more than one data tables on the same SharePoint page.

You have to provide the different ID for each table in your HTML and JS.

**For Example**:

**Table 1** - showing employees from "DirectorList" list:

HTML:

```
<table id="Employee" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

JS:

```
$('#Employee').DataTable({
    "aaData": data.d.results,
    "aoColumns": [
        {
            "mData": "Title"
        },
        {
            "mData": "First_Names"
        },
        {
            "mData": "Last_Name"
        }
    ]
});
```

---

**Table 2** - showing products from "Products" list (list & column names used are just for examples):

HTML:

```
<table id="Products" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

JS:

```
$('#Products').DataTable({
    "aaData": data.d.results,
    "aoColumns": [
        {
            "mData": "Title"
        },
        {
            "mData": "ProductName"
        },
        {
            "mData": "ProductCategory"
        }
    ]
});
```

Where `Title`, `ProductName`, `ProductCategory`, etc. are the internal names of your columns from SharePoint list.

You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Tried using different table IDs but I get the error message: "Datatables warning: table id=Products. Cannot reinitialise DataTable".

Comment: What is the error message? Did you try using different table IDs in both HTML and JS as given in above answer?

Comment: I think you are re-initializing same table multiple times somehow. So, try adding `"bDestroy": true` or `"destroy": true` in datatable options as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708781/datatables-warningtable-id-example-cannot-reinitialise-data-table

Comment: Hi @BraTabs, any update on this? Please accept it as an answer if it helped you in any way.